How stop rendering dead key before the second key is pressed
I'm using a portuguese keyboard layout, and if I want to make the character ã, for example, I have to press ~ and then a. However, when I press ~, it immediately sends the ~ click to the applications, and the character is rendered on the screen.
I don't want to render the ~ before the next character is pressed for reasons, such as that counting as a mistake in typeracer.com. How do I make my system behave as Windows in this sense?
Edit: please for KDE Plasma, but I believe a GNOME solution would probably work.

Have you tried holding down the first key and pressing the second?

It normally should work as you expect: you press the "dead key" then the compose character is rendered when you press the second key. It will help to provide the specific name and variant of the keyboard layout that is active in your case. The only cause I can imagine is that your keyboard layout is not the one you expect.

Holding down the first key and pressing the second gives same results.
I'm using Portuguese (Brasil)
